# jMeter how to check if all threads were successful

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

I have jMeter suite containing several thread groups, which for their part contain several request tests.

At the end I have a SMTP sampler, which I only want to use (in fact send an email on if condition) if all of previoud tests within the threads ran well, means were successful and are showed as "green" in my view result tree.

All I could found on this is https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie resp “${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}”

Last sample is not af any use in my case, so Im assuming this is not applicable for my case. Have anybody done something similar already and can provide any hints? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the title should be of course: jMeter how to check all threads were successful

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Thread Group and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
           if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
                   vars.put('sendEmail', 'false')
           }
   ```

   If **any** sampler fails - it will create `${sendEmail}` JMeter Variable with the value of `false`
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) to the end of your Thread Group and use the following condition:

   ```
   "${sendEmail}" != "false"
   ```
3. Put SMTP Sampler as a child of the If Controller.

This way SMTP Sampler will be executed only if there were no failed samplers.